# Laravel: created new eloquent model, but laravel does not recognize it

Tags: php, exception, laravel

My new model:

```
<?php

class Style extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'styles';

}
```

Defined route:

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => '/templates'), function(){
   Route::post('/style-create', array('uses' => 'StyleController@postCreateStyle', 'as' => 'postCreateStyle'));
});
```

And the model's controller:

```
<?php

class StyleController extends BaseController {

    public function postCreateStyle() {

        $style = new Style();
        $style->save();

        return Redirect::route('getStyleHome');
    }

}
```

And the html form:

```
<form role="form" method="post" action="{{ URL::route('postCreateStyle') }}">
   <!-- FIELDS -->

   <input type="submit" value="{{ isset($style) ? 'Save' : 'Create' }} template" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" />
</form>
```

And if I hit submit, I'm getting this error:

```
[2015-04-28 14:11:59] production.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with message 'Call to undefined method Style::save()' in C:\xampp\htdocs\cspage\app\controllers\StyleController.php:18
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: Illuminate\Exception\Handler->handleShutdown()
#1 {main} [] []
```

I have restarted xampp, re-imported the entire database, I have cleared the auto-load: `php artisan dump-autoload` but the error still exists. What have I done wrong?

Comment: Do you have a migration called `style` by any chance? Also, I assume this is L4?

Comment: Try to `php composer dump-autoload` as well.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how Laravel's internal structure works, but the problem was caused by the migration and the model's name. It was the same. As suggested by @ceejayoz, I have created a new migration: `create_styles_table` and recreated the model: `Style`

Answer (score 0):

> I don't know how Laravel's internal structure works, but the problem was caused by the migration and the model's name. It was the same. As suggested by @ceejayoz, I have created a new migration: create_styles_table and recreated the model: Style

Laravel 4's lack of namespacing means you have to be a little careful with the naming of classes. If you do `php artisan migrate:make style` it'll make a new class called `Style`. If you create a `Style` model, Laravel may load the migration class instead of the Eloquent model you're expecting - and as such, it'll lack the expected functions.

In Laravel 5, namespacing means there's no conflict between the `App\Style` model and the `Style` migration (but you do have to be a little careful still with migration names - I suggest something clearer like `create_styles_table`).